# Perforce - Latin characters in filenames creates issue while getting file history

Tags: character-encoding, perforce, p4v, p4java

I have renamed a file (on windows host using p4v client) to ***CDNÍs.txt*** (I with acute. Now when i try to read this file using p4v on Mac host. I get the file name as CDN�s.txt and p4v fails to load the history of this file.
Similar is the case with p4Java api's.

Also when I checkout the same file on mac host. Same filename becomes CDN%EDs.txt.

I tried my perforce server to run in unicode b using command p4d -xi
but still not able to resolve the issue.

Attached are the screenshots from both Windows host and Mac Host.enter image description here[image: Screeshot from windows host]

[image: screenshot from Mac host where latin characters are not read properly]